# Return type of numpy.minimum()?

Tags: python, types, numpy, int32

When I use the `numpy` functions `minimum()` and `maximum()` on boolean arrays, the type of the result prints as `numpy.int32`. However, a comparison with the `numpy.int32` type fails (even after a cast). Is this a bug?

```
g = np.ones((5, 5), dtype = np.bool)
h = np.maximum(g, 4)
i = np.int32(h)

print 'type of g ', g.dtype.type   # prints <type 'numpy.bool_'>
print 'type of h ', h.dtype.type   # prints <type 'numpy.int32'>
print 'type of i ', i.dtype.type   # prints <type 'numpy.int32'>

print h.dtype.type == i.dtype.type # prints True
print h.dtype.type == np.int32     # prints False
print i.dtype.type == np.int32     # prints False
print i.dtype.type == np.bool_     # prints False
```

Comment: numpy.maximum(x1, x2[, out]) is not the max() function. maximum is the element-wise maximum of array elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems normal enough to me. Using `np.maximum` returns the maximum of `g` and `4`, which is `4` (`True == 1`). You get a matrix full of fours, which *is* integer type.

If you use this syntax for your type comparisons, they work: `h.dtype.type == np.dtype(np.int32)` or more simply `h.dtype == np.int32`.

Comment: interger type is ok. but why isnt it a numpy.int32 (see example)?

Comment: Thanks, this was not obvious to me, as the printed string and the output of type() is exactly the same

Comment: If you try `type(np.int32)`, `type(h.dtype)`, `type(h.dtype.type)` and `type(np.dtype(np.int32))` you will see that some are of type "type" while others are of type "numpy.dtype", hence the difference (if this sentence is understandable).

Comment: i stumbled on this, because in  scipy.ndimage.label() raises an exception if if `output.dtype.type != numpy.int32` . they should use the comparison you posted.

Answer (score 2):

The return type is an **array**:

numpy.minimum(x1, x2[, out])

Element-wise minimum of array elements.

Compare two arrays and returns a new array containing the element-wise minima. If one of the elements being compared is a nan, then that element is returned. If both elements are nans then the first is returned. The latter distinction is important for complex nans, which are defined as at least one of the real or imaginary parts being a nan. The net effect is that nans are propagated.

Parameters :
x1, x2 : array_like
The arrays holding the elements to be compared. They must have the same shape, or shapes that can be broadcast to a single shape.
Returns :
y : {ndarray, scalar}
The minimum of x1 and x2, element-wise. Returns scalar if both x1 and x2 are scalars.

From: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html?highlight=minimum#numpy.minimum

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentaation for np.maximum, you know it compares two arrays, or in your case an array and a scalar.  So it will return 4 for every element of g.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that there are two integer types in C: `int` and `long`, and they can both be 32-bit on 32-bit platforms. The current implementation in Numpy creates a separate scalar type for both. The two are treated the same in `dtype` comparisons when they are the same size (`dtypes` are descriptors for the contents of the arrays -- separate from scalar types). Nevertheless, the fact that there are actually two 32-bit integer scalar types shows up if you go comparing the scalar types directly.

Yes, it's a bit confusing, and will probably be fixed at some point.

However, you will run into the same issue when comparing `int == np.int32`. The correct way is to compare `dtypes` rather than scalar types.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange.. I think there is something odd going on.
I do notice though that

`h.dtype == np.int32 # True`